# SVN failed to check out an app wicause of special windows folder name "aux"

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn

I face a problem with an application which has folder "aux" . When I try to check out the app , svn failed on "aux" invalid folder name.
I understand this is a problem of windows with specials folders names.

Any idea how can resolve this problem .

Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AUX is simply not a valid pathname on windows. See [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx).

Your only real option if you want to check this project out to a Windows system is to rename the directory on the SVN server.

Of course this could be easier said than done.  If the directory name is part of a Java package structure for instance then that means you would have to refactor the code and rename the package(s) wherever they are used.

Also if there are other config files, etc. that reference this directory they would also need to be changed.

Unfortunately for you whoever named this directory aux was not aware it would break on Windows or perhaps never anticipated the need to check the project out on Windows.